# How to assign props values to styles

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using create react app and I need to assign props values to a styles of the component. In this case **background image 'url'** is need to pass as props to styles.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Background from "./background";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Background source="./assets/image.jpg" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

background.js

```
import React from "react";

const styles = {
  backgroundImage: "url()"
};

export default class Background extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={styles.background} />;
  }
}
```

Find the code on below link:
[codcodesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-elion-zz6wr)

Comment: in Background component access through this.props.source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can create style object and update the component style prop with it like so:

```js
  render() {
    const style = {
      backgroundImage:`url(${this.props.image})`
    }
    return <div style={style} />;
  }
```

[check this code update](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-robinson-6z5rd?fontsize=14)